# Enabling Major Push on Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, push-upgrade

I understand that you need to log a case in the partner portal to enable Push Major on a managed package.  My question is, do you need to do this every time you have a major release to Push?  Once enabled, is it always enabled no matter the version?

Thanks!
Jamie

Answer (score 5):

We have this enabled, once this is enabled your good to go as many times as you like, no need to involve Salesforce Support again. Just in case you have not come across it yet, the [ISVForce guide](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf) is an excellent resource on the process and generally.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, once enabled, it is always enabled no matter the version.** However note that pushing Major Versions may involve reaching out to Salesforce twice. Here's what worked for me:

If you already have Push Upgrades, **you will still need to open a case** in the [partner portal](https://www.salesforce.com/partners/login/) under the category *AppExchange & Feature Requests* > *Feature/License Request in Trial or DE Org*:

[image: case-comment]

1. from Setup > Packages > [Your Package] go to Versions > **Push Upgrades** as usual:
2. then hit **Schedule Push Upgrade**

   [image: schedule-push-upgrades]
3. note the subtle change to the selection dialogue, which will now show **major versions**!

   [image: push-major]

Enjoy! **[Remember, with great power comes great responsibility](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_push_about.htm).**